# read_csv not defined error recurring in jupyter notebook while loading dataset from URL

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I tried the same code yesterday and it was working fine. Today when I resumed from where I left I encurred this error.

```
...
# Load dataset
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/iris.csv"
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
dataset = read_csv(url, names=names)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/iris.csv"
      4 names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
----> 5 dataset = read_csv(url, names=names)

NameError: name 'read_csv' is not defined
```

Comment: import the pandas module and then use `dataset = pandas.read_csv(url,names=names)`

Comment: `from pandas import read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you deleted some pieces by mistake. The code should be

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(url, names=names)
```